# Bootstrap nav-tabs display too tightly in Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I have a problem with bootstrap `nav-tabs`. In Google Chrome, `nav-tabs` displays properly, but in Mozilla Firefox it displays too tightly. I have no idea how to fix it.

```
.nav-tabs > li > a:hover{
    display: inline-block;
    color:white !important;
    background: rgba(202, 171, 119, 0.5) !important;
}

.nav-tabs>li>a{
    display: inline-block !important;
    width:100% !important;
    color:black !important;
    padding: 10px 14.86px;
}
```

Comment: an jsfiddle would be nice but your problem is browser based. You can add some extra padding or margin but ti will make your tabs even more loose in chrome.

Comment: Try using reset.css file and then apply your own style.css

Comment: CSS Reset helped. Thanks!